# How does cross validating with Keras fit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, cross-validation, k-fold

I have a fairly small amount of data so I decided to try cross validation, in order to get predictions for all data., like so:

```py
for train_index, test_index in KFold(9, shuffle = True, random_state = 42).split(range(len(df))):
    train_data, test_data = df[train_index], df[test_index]
    train_images, test_images = images[train_index], images[test_index]
    train_labels, test_labels = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]

    model.fit([train_data, train_images], train_labels, epochs = 100, batch_size = 5)

    model.predict([test_data, test_images])
```

It is my understanding that doing this will train a *new* model every time (total of 9 times). However if this is the case then my loss output makes no sense:[image]

The top grey curve is the first iteration and it starts from nearly 1, then goes down. Subsequent iterations are then all significantly lower.

I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong here - I want to fully train new networks 9 times then get predictions each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `model.fit`, the parameter estimation will continue where it left off, so you're right, once you reach the second iteration of your loop, you will be using whatever you achieved in the first iteration.

To avoid this, you will want to reset the parameters of your model between each iteration. One approach would be to simply create the model from scratch in each iteration. The only thing to be aware of is that by default, weights are initialized with random values (to avoid local extrema of the objective), so if you simply reinitialize the model entirely, you will be using different random starting points. To avoid this, and to make sure that you use the same starting point for each iteration, you could either fix the initial values (e.g. by fixing the random seed), or just go with what Keras gives you, then use `model.save` prior to the first iteration, and `load_model` at the start of each iteration, i.e. do what amounts to

```py
from keras.models import load_model

model = ...
model.save('initial.h5')
for ... in KFold
    model = load_model('initial.h5')
    model.fit(...)
    model.predict(...)
```

Not that you necessarily have to worry about this: You could also simply choose to view the random initialization as part of the abstract statistical model whose generalization error you are trying to estimate and just be happy with a new starting point for each iteration.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! But I don't agree with the last remark. If iteration 2 picks up where iteration 1 left off, then it means some samples on which iteration 1 was trained are now left out for *further* training and will be validated on at the end of iteration 2, which is a problem. So a full restart is in order if I want to avoid major bias.

Comment: Maybe my last remark was unclear: Certainly you should worry about picking up information from iteration 1. What you could choose not to worry about is whether you use the exact same starting point for each iteration, of if just using a (new) random starting point for each iteration is alright.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer helpful, you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @fuglede, I would suggest you to use [`validation_split`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) argument in `model.fit`. You don't need to do the split yourself. Keras takes care of that.